# Docker-compose giving URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme postgresql does not accept registry part: $DB_USER:$DB_PASSWORD@$DB_HOST:port (orbad hostname?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I am using multi containers for a ruby app. The containers are working fine but when it comes to creating database using `docker-compose run app rails db:create` I get the following error. 
`rails aborted!
URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme postgresql does not accept registry part: $DB_USER:$DB_PASSWORD@$DB_HOST:port (orbad hostname?)`.

A snippet of the docker-compose file is shown below

```
db:
image: postgres:9.4
volumes_from:
  - data
environment:
  POSTGRES_USER: cpostgres
  POSTGRES_DB: micro_login_db
ports:
  - 5432

app:
build: .
depends_on:
  - db
volumes:
  - .:/webapp
command: rails server -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
ports:
  - 3000:3000
environment:
   DB_HOST: db
   DB_USER: cpostgres
   POSTGRES_DB: micro_login_db
   POSTGRES_TEST_DB: micro_login_test
```

Someone else suggested I create a file named `application.yml` with the following details

```
DB_USER: 'cpostgres'
DB_PASSWORD: ''
DB_HOST: 'db'
POSTGRES_DB: 'micro_login_db'
port: 5432
```

And finally the `database.yml` file

```
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
template: template0
encoding: unicode
username: <%= ENV['DB_USER'] %> 
database: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_DB'] %>
host: <%= ENV['DB_HOST'] %>
pool: 5
timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
```

Question is, why am I getting this error? How can I solve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your `POSTGRES_DB` value has underscore. Have you tried removing those?

Hostname with underscores are known to be problematic sometimes.

[Reference](https://github.com/errbit/errbit/issues/1206#issuecomment-406382724)

Comment: underscore in the hostname was my case. dash was ok though :|